# Play video from url in objective c with buffering

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi everyone I am working on an application in which I have a url of video and I have to play a video  from that url. I have done this job from this code

```
- (IBAction)btnPlayVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSString *fileName = @"Server Address/Vdieo.flv";

    NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

    mPlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];


    [self.view addSubview:mPlayerVC.view];

    //play movie

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [mPlayerVC moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    player.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];

}
```

//============Other Methods====================

```
- (void)willEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willEnterFullscreen");
}

- (void)enteredFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"enteredFullscreen");
}

- (void)willExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willExitFullscreen");
}

- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"exitedFullscreen");
    [mPlayerVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    mPlayerVC = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason intValue]) {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Ended");
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Error");
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: User Exited");
            NSLog(@"exitedFullscreen");

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [mPlayerVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    mPlayerVC = nil;

}
```

My problem is that when this code run video player open and start loading and it takes too much time to run a video. Can anybody guide me how to run video in fast way from internet?

Comment: What is video format and resolution? Can you give video example, which you using?

Comment: I am using .flv format which url comes from server side.

Comment: I have similar problem, and it happens only with 1080 video in landscape format. I want to check what is your video format. Can you send a link to video or attach it?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the code that suggests that lag is anything other than the time it takes to make the request and sufficiently buffer.  The most common technique to improve UE is to start loading as early as possible, even before the user requests playback.

If this is possible, the code should be reorganized as follows:

```
// hang on to the movie player
@property(nonatomic,retain) MPMoviePlayerController *mp;

// call this as soon as its possible to know the user might want to see the video
- (void)primeVideo {
    NSString *fileName = @"Server Address/Vdieo.flv";
    NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];

    // do this also in dealloc
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    mp.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [mp prepareToPlay];
    self.mp = mp;
}
```

That does as much prep as possible without changing the UI.  The rest of your code from the button action is left, tweaked a little...

```
- (IBAction)btnPlayVideo:(id)sender {

    // if there's any way that the user can request playback before
    // you've called primeVideo, check for that here.  But hopefully you
    // can call primeVideo before user even sees the play button
    if (!self.mp) [self primeVideo];

    self.mp.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mp.view];

    MPMovieLoadState state = [self.mp loadState];
    if (state & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) [self.mp play];
    else self.mp.shouldAutoplay = YES;
}
```

Comment: this code does not work. It opens video player and stuck on loading. I already tried this sort of code.

Comment: The code runs in a shipped app.  Consider -- as a debug step -- running with a video file that's in your app's bundle.  Or a smaller remote file.  Also, consider subscribing to loadStateDidChange notification, you can watch progress (and catch errors) there.

Comment: Just noticed the file extension.  iPhone doesn't play flash.  You're going to have to re-encode with ffmpeg or something like it.